# Try / Except, back to try

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code

```
def ID():
    ID = input("Enter ID: ")

    try:
        int(ID)
        print("Good ID")
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a string")


ID()
```

how can I do to try again to input the ID without restarting the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a while loop. There are several ways. Here is one:

```
def ID():
    goodID = False
    while not goodID:
        ID = input("Enter ID: ")
        try:
            int(ID)
            print("Good ID")
            goodID = True
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a string")  # do you mean int??

ID()
```

I would suggest to read also [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232465/how-to-repeat-try-except-block).